# How can I programmatically add data to an address field?

Tags: 8, entities, migrations

I'm trying to import user data from a json file. So far I managed to import most of the information, but now I'm stuck on the address field (created with Address module for Drupal 8).
In the json file (exported from a Drupal 7 website), there is city, country code and country name.

How can I import this data into the new field (the machine name is *field_address*)?

So far I tried using `Drupal::entityTypeManager`.

```php
$values = array(
            'name' => $user["name"],
            'pass' => '',
            'status' => $user["status"],
            'mail' => $user["e_mail"],
            'field_first_name' => $user["first_name"],
            'field_last_name' => $user["last_name"],
            'field_address' => $city,
        );

        $userStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');
        $userEntity = $userStorage->create($values);
```

It doesn't work: The address field stays empty.

Should I use the sub fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [4k4 answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297820/how-can-i-programmatically-add-data-to-an-address-field/297831#297831) I was able to import the data. Here is the code:

```
$adressCountryCode = "NL";
$addressCity = "Amsterdam";

$values = [
  'name' => $user["name"],
  'pass' => '',
  'status' => $user["status"],
  'mail' => $user["e_mail"],
  'field_address' => [
     'country_code' => $adressCountryCode,
     'locality' => $addressCity,
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a field with multiple properties then use an extra array:

```
$values = [
  'name' => $user["name"],
  'pass' => '',
  'status' => $user["status"],
  'mail' => $user["e_mail"],

  'field_address' => [
    'first_name' => $user["first_name"],
    'last_name' => $user["last_name"],
    'city' => $city,
  ],
];
```